# Strange Fsi.exe behavior

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I'm observing some strange behavior when using the F# interactive interpreter.

Running the following code:

```
let getType1 = Type.GetType("namespace.does.not.exist, doesntexistlib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",false);;
let getType2 = Type.GetType("namespace.does.not.exist, doesntexistlib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",false);;
```

results in fsi catching a FileLoadException even though the throwOnError parameter is set to false. The first time it returns a null second time the exception occurs.

Running the same code in a regular program (not interactively) results in expected behavior where getType = null.

Does FSI.exe stop on all exceptions? Is it possible to set FSI to ignore these exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the stack trace, it looks like FSI is hooking into its AppDomain's assembly resolution.  Unfortunately FSI is throwing the exception itself when it can't resolve the assembly - this isn't being generated by framework code, and that's why your `throwOnError` parameter isn't being respected - FSI's exception is just propagating upwards and then being caught at the top level.  To me, this looks like a bug in FSI, but it may be that the available hooks in the AppDomain's assembly resolution process don't provide FSI with enough information to determine when it's okay to throw.

**EDIT** - If you look into the source file fsi.fs (included in the F# distribution in the source/fsharp/Fsi directory), you can see where this handler is hooked up (it's in the frighteningly named `MagicAssemblyResolution` module).  It appears that FSI needs to hook into the resolution process so that assemblies registered via the `#r` directive can be found, but I can't tell at a glance where things are going wrong, or why no exception is thrown all the way to the top level the first time you try to resolve an invalid assembly.